# What is correct way to generate and handle exceptions when using Flux from projectreactor

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I am using io.projectreactor 3 (reactor-core 3.2.6.RELEASE) and I have noticed some discrepancies regarding error handling. Unfortunately, official documentation does not provide enough details to solve my problems.

I have following 4 snippets. In some cases exception will be ignored and in other cases it will thrown further. What is the way to actually produce and consume exceptions?

**Snippet 1**

In this case, exception will be ignored and main() will complete without receiving exception.

```java
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        Flux.push(sink -> {
            sink.next(1);
            sink.next(2);
        }).doOnNext(e -> {
            throw new RuntimeException("HELLO WORLD");
        }).subscribe(System.out::println, e -> {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        });
        System.out.println("DONE");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
DONE
```

**Snippet 2**

Is similar as example from above, except that we don't use Flux.push but Flux.just. Main() will receive exception.

```java
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        Flux.just(
                1
        ).doOnNext(e -> {
            throw new RuntimeException("HELLO WORLD");
        }).subscribe(System.out::println, e -> {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        });
        System.out.println("DONE");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: HELLO WORLD
    at Scratch.lambda$main$1(scratch_15.java:10)
...
```

**Snippet 3**

We signal exception by calling sink.error. Main() will not receive exception.

```java
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        Flux.push(sink -> {
            sink.next(1);
            sink.next(2);
            sink.error(new RuntimeException("HELLO WORLD"));
        }).subscribe(System.out::println, e -> {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        });
        System.out.println("DONE");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
DONE
```

**Snippet 4**

We throw exception directly. Main() will receive exception.

```java
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        Flux.push(sink -> {
            sink.next(1);
            sink.next(2);
            throw new RuntimeException("HELLO WORLD");
        }).subscribe(System.out::println, e -> {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        });
        System.out.println("DONE");
    }
}
```

Output

```
1
2
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: HELLO WORLD
    at Scratch.lambda$main$1(scratch_15.java:10)
...
```

What is the correct way to handle exception when working with reactive-core? The only reliable way seems not to use error callback at all, and instead surround flux.subscribe with try/catch. But in that case I always receive `UnsupportedOperationException` instead of original exception, and then I need to use `Exceptions.isErrorCallbackNotImplemented` to check if it comes from reactive, extract nested exception and then throw it.

This can be done of course, but it needs to be done consistently on every place where we use Flux is being subscribed. That does not looks nice to me. What I'm missing here?

Comment: in *Snippet 1* you've got `main()` method finished execution earlier than the `subscribe()` method lambdas get call back (because execution is asynchronous). If you add `Thread.sleep()` before final `println()` you'll see it.

Answer (score 4):

In all your examples the problem is re-throwing from the `.subscribe(...)` error-handling lambda.

If you want the exception to be thrown in a main block, use `block()` variants.

If you want to test that the error is propagated throughout the pipeline, use `StepVerifier.create(pipeline).expectError(...).verify()`.

`.subscribe` in general is to get notified of "terminal" state, not intended to recover or re-throw errors (use `onError*` operators upstream for that).

The `just`-based examples seem to correctly propagate the exception because they execute no user-provided code at subscription, so no try/catch is in place during `subscribe(Consumer<Throwable>)`.

`push`, like `generate`/`create`/`defer` and `compose`, execute some user-defined logic (the `Consumer<FluxSink>`), at subscription. They guard against the whole `Consumer` throwing exceptions and try to propagate that (as an `onError` signal) rather than directly throwing it.

But if the failure in the `Consumer` is caused while executing one of the `sink`'s methods, it can be problematic if the `subscriber` re-throws: we enter a recursion where calling the sink calls the sink. We protect against this infinite case by exiting when we detect recursive draining of the sink.

This is why `push`-based examples that trigger error after `sink.next` or in `sink.error` (examples 1 and 3) fail to produce the exception in the main:

1. `Consumer` is applied
2. `sink.next` is called and next operator creates exception 1, or `sink.error` is called
3. exception 1 reaches `subscribe` and is re-thrown as exception 2
4. this short-circuits the `Consumer.apply`, exception 2 is passed to `sink.error`
5. the sink is already being called so we break out to avoid infinite recursion
6. exception 2 is never seen

In example 4 on the other hand, we're no longer in the middle of calling the sink's methods, and the original exception doesn't reach the subscriber first:

1. `Consumer` is applied
2. it directly throws exception 1
3. this short-circuits the `Consumer.apply` and exception 1 is passed to `sink.error`
4. which propagates to the subscribe
5. which re-throws it as exception 2
6. exception 2 is seen in the main method

Comment: If I understood you correctly, instead of using `.subscribe(this::finalConsumer)`, I should be doing `.doOnNext(this::finalConsumer).blockLast()` in order to get my exception?

Comment: depends on what exactly you're trying to achieve with the consumers. the main goal should be to get rid of `throw` inside the `Consumer<Throwable>` you pass to `subscribe`. if you did that to assert the exception for testing purposes, replace that process with a `StepVerifier`. If there is some business logic to the exception wrapping / re-throw, replace it using a `.onErrorMap` before the `subscribe`.

Comment: I am not talking about testing, I really want for exception to be thrown on place where I subscribe to flux. But even if I use `.onErrorMap` and then `.subscribe`, I will still not get my exception, but will get exception packed into `reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented` which I don't like. The only way to get original exception thrown seems to be `.doOnNext(this::finalConsumer).blockLast()`. I am ok with that, I just need to get used to that construct instead of using `.subscribe()`

Comment: yeah, well, as I said: in Reactor, throwing is NOT a first class citizen and is only accepted in lambda as a quality of life feature (the operator using the lambda will convert that to a `onError` signal). `subscribe(...)` is not intended to throw, because it can execute asynchronously (in which case the thrown exception could be overlooked). if you want subscribing code to throw, then it means what you really  want is to revert back to imperative and blocking programming, and that's what `.block*` operators are intended for (subscribe and wait for a value or throw an exception).