# FluxSink.next() throw error/exception, if error thrown in processor by user

Tags: reactive-programming, project-reactor

```
   Flux.<Integer>push(sink -> {
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10 && !sink.isCancelled(); i++) {
                sink.next(i);
            }
            sink.complete();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error in wrong place " + e);
        }
    })
            .doOnNext(i -> { if (i % 5 == 0) throw new RuntimeException("Error"); })
            .subscribe(i -> System.out.println("i = " + i));
```

Output of this code is

```
  `Error in wrong place reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error`
```

it means that exception is rethrown by **`sink.next(i);`** in push method and not push to error reactive channel. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is pushed to flux error channel, but You have no error subscriber on this channel, You can add:

```
.doOnError(e -> System.out.println("Now error in good place = " + e))
```

or

```
.subscribe(i -> System.out.println("i = " + i), e -> System.out.println("Now error in good place = " + e));
```

The full code then is:

```
   Flux.<Integer>push(sink -> {
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10 && !sink.isCancelled(); i++) {
                sink.next(i);
            }
            sink.complete();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error in wrong place " + e);
        }
    })
            .doOnNext(i -> { if (i % 5 == 0) throw new RuntimeException("Error"); })
            .doOnError(e -> System.out.println("Now error in good place = " + e)) //it's missing
            .subscribe(i -> System.out.println("i = " + i));
```

Also see this answer, why You need subscriber and standard (fox *next()*) `subscriber` is not throwing an error: [What is correct way to generate and handle exceptions when using Flux from projectreactor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55045638/6329755)